Chat search fails to return more than 10000 messages
Chat search is currently unable to return any more than approximately 10000 messages, instead returning "0 messages found". I'm pretty sure it didn't do that before.
The limit seems to be around 10000 messages overall, regardless of page size:

Page size 50 (default): 199 works, 200 fails
Page size 100: 99 works, 100 fails
Page size 20: 499 works, 500 fails

